# Trouble logging into salesforce

Tags: login-errors, forgot-your-password

I have reset my password recently,and I am not able to login with the changed password and it shows "invalid user name and password".If try using "forget password" method,I am receiving a mail saying account is being temporarily locked and have to wait for 60 min.Trying the same procedure again after 60 min gives back the same mail asking to wait for another 60 min and account has been locked?what would be the problem?how can I contact the support team?

Comment: Make sure that you are accessing the correct URL - if you try a sandbox account on the https://salesforce.com/login page it will reject and likewise for an account from live if you try going to https://test.salesforce.com it will again never find the user account. Easiest fix is if there is another admin on the Salesforce org request they unlock the account and reset the password.

Comment: Its not my sandbox account. I have tried using all the procedures you told  but its not working.and there is only one admin for my org.

Comment: There isn't an automated tool trying to use the previous credentials still? It could be locking you out.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you need to contact Salesforce support directly.

Comment: Yeah contacted and resolved the issue as suggested.Thanks.